# Copy column based on range

Tags: vba

Function finds out if the cell in the range is not numeric and copy the selected range from the other sheet.
But I cannot get past this.

```
Sub paste()  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lt As String
    Dim sn As String
    sn = ActiveSheet.Name

    For Each c In Range("a6:ck6")
        If c.Value.IsNumber() Then
            Sheets("1").Select
            Range("D8:D69").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets(sn).Select
            MsgBox Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1) = lt
            Cells(8, lt).Paste
        Else
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim c As Range, col As String
With Sheets(sn) '~~> Explicitly provide the sheet name here
    For Each c In .Range("A6:CK6")
        If Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            col = Split(c.address, "$")(1)
            Sheets("1").Range(col & "8:" & col & "69").Copy c.Offset(2,0)
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Above code checks if A6:CK6 for non numeric values.
If so, it will copy values on Sheet named "1" on the same column from row 8 to 69.
Is this what you're trying?